# Unmarshal JSON data of unknown format

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

My JSON is in the following format:

```
{
'Math': 
[
    {'Student1': 100.0, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2017-06-26 15:30:00'), 'Student2': 100.0, 'Student3': 97.058823442402414},
    {'Student1': 93.877550824911907, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2017-06-26 15:31:00'), 'Student2': 100.0, 'Student5': 100.0},
    {'Student8': 100.0, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2017-06-26 15:32:00'), 'Student10': 100.0, 'Student4': 100.0}
],
'English': [
    {'Student1': 100.0, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2017-06-26 15:30:00'), 'Student5': 100.0, 'Student3': 97.058823442402414},
    {'Student1': 93.877550824911907, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2017-06-26 15:31:00'), 'Student2': 100.0, 'Student5': 100.0}, 
    {'Student8': 100.0, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2017-06-26 15:32:00'), 'Student10': 100.0, 'Student4': 100.0}
]
}
```

The keys are completely unknown to me. All I know is that the JSON will be of the format:

```
{
SUBJECT1: [{Student_Name1: Grade, Student_Name2: Grade, ... , Student_Name3: Grade, timestamp: Timestamp(...)}],
SUBJECT2: [{Student_Name4: Grade, Student_Name6: Grade, ... , Student_Name5: Grade, timestamp: Timestamp(...)}]
...
SUBJECTN: [{Student_Name1: Grade, Student_Name6: Grade, ... , Student_Name9: Grade, timestamp: Timestamp(...)}]
}
```

where the `subjects`, `student_names` are all unknown and could vary.

I want to unmarshal this into a GoLang struct so I can return it to my front-end as a JSON object. What should my struct look like? This is what I tried, but it didn't work.

```
type GradeData struct {
    Grades map[string]interface{} `json:"-"`
}
```

Comment: What didn't work about it? Unmarshalling to a `map[string]interface{}` is appropriate. From there you can iterate over the keys and unmarshal the value into an array.

Comment: Is your JSON data is valid?

Comment: @jeevatkm thanks. My JSON was full of escape characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- If you don't know the keys, you can use `map[string]interface{}` to unmarshal your JSON payload.
- If you use `json:"-"` tag for the `struct` fields, those fields will be ignored during JSON Marshal/Unmarshal.

You can try following options: [Go Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/30ko3Z14Mx)

**Option 1:**

```
var grades map[string]interface{}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &grades)
fmt.Println(err)

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", grades)
```

**Option 2:** if you want have `struct`

```
var gradesData GradeData
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &gradesData.Grades)
fmt.Println(err)

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", gradesData)
```