# How to model a Go struct after a JSON that has object values with arbitrary keys?

Tags: json, go

I am making an http request to an API from my go program. The request body is a JSON object as below:

```
 {
      "data": {
          "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX": { 
              "status": "ok","message":"aaa","details":"bbb"
          },
          "ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ": { 
              "status": "ok","message":"ccc","details":"ddd" 
          }  
     }
}
```

Where `"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"` is an arbitrary key itself.

How to define a struct that allows that part to take a string value? Below is my struct, which I know does not allow me to properly decode the JSON:

```
type ReceiptResult struct {
    Data   ReceiptIDS    `json:"data"`
}

type ReceiptIDS struct {
    ReceiptID struct {
        Status  string `json:"status,omitempty"`
        Message string `json:"message,omitempty"`
        Details string `json:"details,omitempty"`
    }
}
```

Comment: you need the data type to be a map like this 

     ```type ReceiptResult struct{ Data   map[string]ReceiptIDS    `json:"data"`}```

Comment: JSON objects only have keys and values, there is no "tag" vs "string". Are you looking to decode into a map? Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564216/unmarshal-json-with-arbitrary-key-value-pairs-to-struct, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362653/how-to-unmarshal-json-with-unknown-fieldnames-to-struct/49362754#49362754, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773082/unmarshal-json-data-of-unknown-format, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436730/unmarshal-json-with-some-known-and-some-unknown-field-names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the problem here your struct's struct is unneeded.

Structs should look like this

```
type ReceiptResult struct {
    Data map[string]ReceiptIDS `json:"data"`
}

type ReceiptIDS struct {
    Status  string `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Message string `json:"message,omitempty"`
    Details string `json:"details,omitempty"`
}
```

Playground working example: https://play.golang.org/p/EbJ2FhQOLz1