# Unmarshal XML with some unknown tags in golang?

Tags: xml, go

Given an XML raw string of unknown structure (it's from an OCR result), how should I unmarshal the string into a process-able go struct/interface?

For JSON, I could do something like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773645/19287186), is there an XML version for this?

**Example**

```
randomOcrXmlString := `
<container>
<x></x>
<y><z></z><y>
<abc></abc>
... (many more random tags)
</container>`
```

My actual intention - to insert a tag before the closing `</container>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per [`encoding/xml` doc](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshal),

> If the struct has a field of type []byte or string with tag ",innerxml", Unmarshal accumulates the raw XML nested inside the element in that field.

So below worked for me

```
type xmlResponse struct {
    Fields []byte `xml:",innerxml"`
}

func isXMLStringValid(str string) bool {
    // ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/62869933
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(str))
    for {
        err := decoder.Decode(new(interface{}))
        if err != nil {
            return err == io.EOF
        }
    }
}

func parseRawXMLString(xmlStr string) (*xmlResponse, error) {
  if !isXMLStringValid(xmlStr) {
        return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("xml: construct: input is not valid xml: %s", xmlStr))
    }

  var xmlResp = xmlResponse{}
  err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlStr), &xmlResp)
  if err != nil {
        log.Printf("xml: unmarshal: %s", err)
        return nil, err
  }
  return &xmlResp, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating struct like

```
type Container struct {
    X   string `xml:"x" json:"x"`
    Y   Y      `xml:"y" json:"y"`
    Abc string `xml:"abc" json:"abc"`
}
type Y struct {
    Z string `xml:"z" json:"z"`
}
```

unmarshal the xml string using encoding/xml

```
var container Container
_ = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(randomOcrXmlString), &container)
```

check [go play ground](https://go.dev/play/p/Fxs9Z7EGInX)

Comment: Thank you! sadly in my case the struct is unknown due to random ocr result; Anyway I found out sth that worked for me, feel free to leave any comment on my answer